# Size of framebuffer lookup table

Tags: memory-management

> If the frame buffer has 8 bits per pixel and 8 bits are allocated for  each of the R, G, B components, what would be the size of the
>       lookup table?
>       a) 24 bytes
>       b) 1024 bytes
>       c) 768 bytes
>       d) 256 bytes

I read about **Framebuffer** and what I understood is

"*It stores the color values (in case of color frame buffer) in indexed form. So if we have $8-bit$ color, then possible colors are*  $2^8$*So frame buffer would store color values for each pixel on screen and it's size would depend on screen resolution. Corresponding actual color values (or codes) would be stored in lookup table"

So, Lookup table would have 
$2^8 = 256$ entries, which is $256$ bytes, since each entry is of 8-bits = 1 byte.

But that is not the correct answer to above question. So, can anyone tell, **where am I going wrong ?**

Also, question says `frame buffer has 8-bit per pixel and 8-bits are allocated for each RGB` , This means for each pixel, frame buffer has $8,8,8,8$ bits allocated ?

Comment: where did you read that? what are the exact specification? You can't ask these details, as they depend on the information you are given.

Comment: That being said, FWIK,  8-bit RGB, means 8+8+8 bits per pixel. But there may be additional information which is not color related.

Comment: @Ran G. I read this in the competitive exam of `Indian Space Research Organization (ISRO)` for Computer Science Engineers. Only this question is given, nothing else is given as information. I don't have any clue about how to proceed with this. [Here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CFEQFjAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fisrohq.vssc.gov.in%2Fisr0dem0v5a%2Fimages%2Frecruitment_pdf_files%2FQ%2FQP-Comp.Sci-2013.pdf&ei=aZifVKPAMcyxuAS-y4LgAQ&usg=AFQjCNFWlOhZoh2J3xfqO5YYzP0dE6lWog&sig2=skWIP4EzJ5MdU7hL5ojfaQ&bvm=bv.82001339,d.c2E) is the paper - see Q-10

Comment: maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framebuffer#Color_palette) would be helpful.

Comment: The lookup table for what? This is not a standard concept with respect to framebuffers. It looks like there is a color palette involved, but you need to give us all the definitions.

Comment: @Gilles Yes, color palette is involved as pointed out by  Yuval Filmus in the answer. Though question did not had this information, but indeed the color palette thing as pointed by you and Yuval Filmus seems correct

Comment: @Gilles If you did the down vote because of missing information, please see the question paper link I provided. Question provides only as much information as I asked the question

Comment: @Ran G. I don't understand why you are putthing this on hold when Yuval Filmus has already answered it correctly

Comment: Wow, that's a terrible set of exam questions. Not just this question but many others are more about guessing what the exam setter had in mind than about knowledge of computer science. Reading the mind of this exam setter isn't useful knowledge for computer scientists, I don't see how this question as worded could be of interest to anyone except people taking that particular exam.

Comment: @Gilles I agree with you, but there isn't an option. That is the only exam to give to get in to the `ISRO`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that by *framebuffer* they really mean *palette table*, then the table consists of 256 entries, each encoding an RGB color ("true color"). An RGB color takes 24 bits (3 bytes), 8 bits per color component, so in total we need 256$\times$3=768 bytes. That said, it may be easier to access the table if each color takes up an entire dword (32 bits, 4 bytes): for example, indexing could be for free in certain processors. In that case the table would take up 256$\times$4=1024 bytes. However, given the data at your disposal, the best guess would be 768 bytes.

Palette tables are most celebrated for their use in the popular GIF format. GIF uses a color palette consisting of 256 colors (in its most popular version), one possibly being reserved for "transparent", and the colors themselves are stored separately, usually as "true color" 24-bit values. The color table indeed uses 3 bytes per color, for a total of 768 bytes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I couldn't find it anywhere. Your answer is correct. As per the answer-key, it is `768 bytes` :)